# Use FormTheme for CollectionType?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I'm using for my symfony project the Ninsuo JqueryCollection plugin https://symfony-collection.fuz.org/symfony3/, and I have a form that has a collectionType, except that I want the targeted entity to appear with its own layout, but I do not know how to apply it to CollectionType
I have my "subform" like this

**SubForm :**

```
{{form_start(form)}}
    <div class="card">
        <h5 class="card-header">Nouvel utilisateur</h5>
        <div class="card-body">
            {{form_row(form.email)}}

            <div class="row align-items-center">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    {{form_row(form.nom)}}
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    {{form_row(form.prenom)}}
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    {{form_row(form.service)}}
                </div>
            </div>
            {{form_row(form.roles)}}
        </div>
    </div>
{{form_end(form)}}
```

And my main Form :

```
{{form_start(form)}}
    {{form_row(form.utilisateurs, {'attr': {'class': 'my-selector jquery-buttons-collection mt-3'} })}}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enregistrer</button>
    {{form_end(form)}}
```

I would like to apply the layout of the 1st form for my form.users. Someone would know how?

EDIT:

**My main form :**

```
$builder
        ->add('utilisateurs', CollectionType::class, [
            'entry_type' => AdminUserRegistrationType::class,
            'entry_options' => [
                'label' => false,
            ],
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'delete_empty' => true,
            'by_reference' => true,
            'prototype' => true,
            'label' => false,
            'attr' => array(
                'class' => 'my-selector',
                'label' => false,
            ),
            'by_reference' => false,
        ]);
        ;
```

With the template :

```
{{form_start(form)}}
    {{form_row(form.utilisateurs, {'attr': {'class': 'my-selector jquery-buttons-collection mt-3'} })}}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enregistrer</button>
    {{form_end(form)}}
```

**The form.utilisateurs formType :**

```
$builder
            ->add('nom', TextType::class)
            ->add('prenom', TextType::class)
            ->add('email', EmailType::class)
            ->add('service', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => GroupeValidateurs::class,
                'query_builder' => function (GroupeValidateursRepository $repo) {
                    return $repo->createQueryBuilder("g")
                        ->orderBy("g.nom", 'ASC');
                },
                'choice_label' => 'nom',
                'label' => "Service",
                'placeholder' => 'Service'
            ])
            ->add('roles', ChoiceType::class, [
                'label' => "Rôles",
                'choices' => [
                    'Admin' => 'ROLE_ADMIN',
                    'Direction' => 'ROLE_DIRECTION',
                    'RH' => 'ROLE_RH',
                ],
                "expanded" => true,
                "multiple" => true,

            ])
        ;
```

**And the form theme :**

```
{% block utilisateursType_label %}{% endblock %}
{% block utilisateursType_errors %}{% endblock %}

{% block utilisateursType_widget %}

    <div class="card">
        <h5 class="card-header">Nouvel utilisateur</h5>
        <div class="card-body">
            {{form_widget(form.email)}}

            <div class="row align-items-center">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    {{form_widget(form.nom)}}
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    {{form_widget(form.prenom)}}
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    {{form_widget(form.service)}}
                </div>
            </div>
            {{form_widget(form.roles)}}
        </div>
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

But I don't know how find the block name

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand. What layout do you want to apply? How does it differ from what is currently displayed?

Comment: Look this link : https://symfony-collection.fuz.org/symfony3/advanced/customFormTheme
I've a CollectionType with this plugin to add somme "utilisateurs". An user field has a formType to respect.
And I would like a formTheme for my field but I don't know how do this

Comment: I updated my first post